# Does the carrot on a stick method work on a mule?

Tags: zoology

Some idioms ("chase the carrot" / "carrot and stick") and a popular image (as shown below) suggest that you can make a mule move forward (and pull a cart), by placing a carrot or some other food hanging from a stick, in front of its face.

For example, [a dictionary](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=chase%20the%20carrot) of urban idioms explains:

> "chase the carrot": attempting to reach the unreachable, in the old
>   days a carrot was tied to a stick in front of a wagon's mule or
>   stubborn horse to make them step forward and walk ahead... they
>   were never able to reach the carrot.

Is this known to really happen so? Have this (or some variation) been used as a practical locomotive trick? (things like the rabbit at dog races don't count; the key is that the animal itself moves the object it's seeking).

[image: carrot without the stick]

Comment: [carrot and stick](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carrot_and_stick) method usually means punishment and reward, aka hitting with the stick and tempting with the carrot

Comment: Do you need the carrot at all?

Comment: @Gordon it is all about; being bad against it, when it does wrong and being good against it, when it does right.

Comment: From the question description (not the title) I think that Gordon meant this classical image: ![carrot on a stick](http://i.stack.imgur.com/j7nuG.jpg) **BTW** in Czech we do not say "carrot and stick" but "sugar and whip".

Comment: I think it is very clear what is being asked.

Comment: @Chris I think you can can get a mule to pull a cart merely by harnessing it to a cart: neither the carrot nor the stick is always necessary.

Comment: @ChrisW, but does the carrot motivate the mule to walk?  Can you change the mule's direction by moving the carrot and so on?

Comment: @Gordon, I once placed a peg on the end of my dogs tail, and it kept running around in circles trying to reach the peg.

Comment: Can this question be taken off hold? The rewording makes it a lot clearer. Thanks @leonbloy!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes it works to coax the animal to move, but probably not as means for consistent forward locomotion. Some evidence:

- [Footage](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JUJJ2qgyFd8) of a man "training donkey to move with a target stick/lure/feeder."<sup>1</sup>
- Amateur [video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-PVFBGN_zoMH) showing a "pony move under saddle while being baited with a carrot dangling from a string attached to a stick."<sup>2</sup>
- From [*Every Woman's Encyclopedia*](https://web.archive.org/web/20150601161505/http://chestofbooks.com/food/household/Woman-Encyclopaedia-3/A-Children-s-Donkey-Gymkhana.html), 1910-1920:

  > Stick-and-carrot race. Each competitor tries to incite her steed to its top speed by dangling a fine carro' before its nose spirits of the place, who will be sure to enter into the fun, and make things go with a swing, before inviting the less enterprising boys and girls and smaller children.<sup>3</sup>

  [image]

  1. http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JUJJ2qgyFd8
  2. http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-PVFBGN_zoMH
  3. https://web.archive.org/web/20150601161505/http://chestofbooks.com/food/household/Woman-Encyclopaedia-3/A-Children-s-Donkey-Gymkhana.html

Comment: My basic knowledge of animal conditioning tells me it wouldn't work for too long. There must be a reward at least some of the time for any positive conditioning to work. But once conditioned, it might work. There's that old study were a guy conditioned pigeons to peck at a plate until exhaustion.